Adjust text based on screen size in flutter
child: Text(
                    'MENTAL\nPREPARATION',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).headlineMedium.override(
                          fontFamily:
                              FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).headlineMediumFamily,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: () {
                            if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                kBreakpointSmall) {
                              return 32;
                            } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                kBreakpointMedium) {
                              return 35;
                            } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                                kBreakpointLarge) {
                              return 40;
                            } else {
                              return 45;
                            }
                          }()

The text "MENTAL PREPARATION" is a two line text when opened on a smartphone. I want it to change to a single line when opened in Tablet and desktop.
I am not aware of how to go about doing the code changes for the expected functionality

You can check if the current is mobile, desktop or tablet. Here's an example
Manual way:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Responsive extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;

  const Responsive(
      {Key? key,
        required this.mobile,
        required this.tablet,
        required this.desktop})
      : super(key: key);

  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 900 &&
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 900;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder:(context, constraints){
      if(constraints.maxHeight>=900){
        return desktop;
      }
      else if(constraints.maxHeight>=650){
        return desktop;
      }
      else return mobile;
    });
  }
}

//Using above Class
Scaffold(
body: Responsive.isMobile(context) ? Text("Hello\nWorld") : Text("Hello World")
);

Another way: Just use this package

You can try Screen Size Util package to adapt the screen size. You can have a look at the implementation documentation.

                  child: Text(
                () {
                  if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width < kBreakpointSmall) {
                    return 'MENTAL${'\n'}PREPARATION';
                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                      kBreakpointMedium) {
                    return 'MENTAL PREPARATION';
                  } else if (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width <
                      kBreakpointLarge) {
                    return 'MENTAL PREPARATION';
                  } else {
                    return 'MENTAL PREPARATION';
                  }
                }(),

This worked for me

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
